# Are there more customUserNamePasswordValidatorType instances?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

Is there only one instance of `customUserNamePasswordValidatorType` or is it possible that there are more than one instance per "application"?
If there are more instances, is somewhere written the logic, when they are created (e.g. one instance per login, per hour or something else)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there exists only one instance of customUserNamePasswordValidatorType. Regardless of the way that the WCF application runs, single instance or multiple instances there is always one instance of validation logic for everyone consuming the service.

```
using (WebServiceHost sh = new WebServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri))
{
    sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
    ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
    smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
    if (smb == null)
    {
        smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
        {
            HttpGetEnabled = true
        };
        sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
    }
    sh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
    sh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new CustUserNamePasswordVal();
    Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
    sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");
    sh.Opened += delegate
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service is ready");
    };
    sh.Closed += delegate
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Service is clsoed");
    };
    sh.Open();
    Console.ReadLine();
    //pause
    sh.Close();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And the validation class, UserNamePasswordValidator.

```
    internal class CustUserNamePasswordVal : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (userName != "jack" || password != "123456")
            {
                throw new FaultException("Username/Password is not correct");
            }
        }
}
```

Official link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-a-custom-user-name-and-password-validator
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/user-name-password-validator
Maybe I don’t fully understand your mean, feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: I would like to have some values loaded from external sources and loading those values is expensive, so I would like to load them once at start. The question is if I can keep them locally or I have to save them to some static property so they would be accessible to every instance.

Comment: For the default single instance running mode, I think the static property is enough. A local binary file is also a nice idea. Just we may have to pay attention to the problem of resource locks.